# Assistance Implementing A Business Rule in an Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: database, database-design

In a hypothetical scenario where a business requires people to have a membership to use their service, there are three types of memberships: student, corporate, and individual. Student membership is free, but corporate and individual memberships incur a fee.

In order to implement this on an entity relationship diagram, would the following be appropriate?:

[image]

This solution utilizes subtypes/supertypes, with students, corporate, and individuals being subtypes of the membership supertype.

If there is a more appropriate way to handle this, please provide it. I am trying to learn the best practices for database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard ER modeling, the situation you describe is called generalization/specialization.  Students memberships, Corporate memberships, and Individual Memberships are all specialized forms of memberships.  In ER diagrams  (actually EER diagrams) this is depicted as follows:  [Diagram](https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance)

This diagram is for a different case from yours, but the concept of generalization is the same.